# How do you append a set of Series with duplicate label names (index) to the end of a DataFrame as rows without using the deprecated append method?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe, series

I need to append a pandas Series as a row to the end of a pandas Dataframe. What makes this tricky is that I am using dates as my index, which are not unique in my case. This is what I want to be the result with the date values being the index.

```
+───────────+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
|           | counts  | day of week  | weekend  | month  |
+───────────+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
| 8/5/2015  | 1111    | 2            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/5/2015  | 1076    | 3            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/5/2015  | 1060    | 4            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/6/2015  | 1540    | 5            | TRUE     | 8      |
| 8/7/2015  | 1493    | 6            | TRUE     | 8      |
| 8/7/2015  | 1060    | 0            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/7/2015  | 1113    | 1            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/8/2015  | 1027    | 2            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/8/2015  | 1053    | 3            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/8/2015  | 1051    | 4            | FALSE    | 8      |
| 8/8/2015  | 1278    | 5            | TRUE     | 8      |
| 8/8/2015  | 1086    | 6            | TRUE     | 8      |
+───────────+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
```

While this was easily possible with the **append** method, it is being deprecated and I am not sure that **concat** can replicate all of its functionality. (*On a side note, why does the pandas team keep deprecating great functionality?*).

Answer (score 1):

My solution involves the **loc** method:

```
df.loc[len(df)] = series_row

df= df.rename(index={label_name: series_row.name})
```

In case you don't follow, we insert a new row at the end of the Dataframe. If we stop there, the label name will be an int value, specifically the size of the Dataframe.

```
df.loc[len(df)] = series_row

+───+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
|   | counts  | day of week  | weekend  | month  |
+───+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
| 1 | 1111    | 2            | FALSE    | 8      |
+───+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
```

To keep the **append** method's functionality, we need to rename the label to whatever we want which in this case was a date string.

```
df= df.rename(index={label_name: series_row.name})

+───────────+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
|           | counts  | day of week  | weekend  | month  |
+───────────+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
| 8/5/2015  | 1111    | 2            | FALSE    | 8      |
+───────────+─────────+──────────────+──────────+────────+
```